# Measure accelerometer change. not position

Tags: android, accelerometer

I need to be able to measure the change of the accelerometer, not its actual position. I need to move a sprite around with it, and it only works when the device's 'default', if you will, is flat on a table. I need to be able to measure its change. I have heard matrix multiplication and things are needed, but are there any easier ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you register a SensorEventListener, you must Override onSensorChanged(). This returns the change on X, Y, & Z axes. If you want to calculate the rotation matrix from this data, you also need to use the magnetic field sensor. How right? This should get you going:

```
    // Deduced from Accelerometer data
    private float[] gravityMatrix = new float[3];
    // Magnetic field
    private float[] geomagneticMatrix = new float[3];
    private boolean sensorReady = false;
    private int counter = 0;

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        float[] mIdentityMatrix = new float[16];
        mIdentityMatrix[0] = 1;
        mIdentityMatrix[4] = 1;
        mIdentityMatrix[8] = 1;
        mIdentityMatrix[12] = 1;

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            if (counter++ % 10 == 0) {
                gravityMatrix = event.values.clone();
                sensorReady = true;
            }
        }
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            geomagneticMatrix = event.values.clone();

        if (sensorReady)
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix,
                    mIdentityMatrix, gravityMatrix, geomagneticMatrix);
    }
```

Comment: It's really not that hard. You could also use the rotation sensor, but not all devices have this.

Comment: What should I use for mRotationMatrix and where can I get the calculated x, y, and z values? Thanks.